# Why is matplotlib displaying the plot differently in the jupyter notebook than when exported to pdf

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am plotting a graph in my jupyter notebook like this:

```
fig3, ax3 = plt.subplots()

color = 'tab:red'
ax3.set_xlabel('active learning cycles')
ax3.set_ylabel('amount', color=color)
ax3.plot(al_cycle_count, al_bbs_count, color=color)
ax3.plot(al_cycle_count, ccs, color=color, dashes=[6, 2])
ax3.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)

ax4 = ax3.twinx()  # instantiate a second axes that shares the same x-axis

ax4.set_ylabel('% (1 = 100%)')
ax4.plot(al_cycle_count, precisions)
ax4.plot(al_cycle_count, recalls)
ax4.plot(al_cycle_count, f1s)

ax3.set(title='performance of "' + experiment_name + '"')
fig3.legend(['Bounding Boxen', 'Learning Steps', 'Precision', 'Recall', 'F1'], loc='upper right', bbox_to_anchor=(0.35, 0.9))

#fig3.tight_layout()  # otherwise the right y-label is slightly clipped
plt.show()
```

And the output looks like this:

[image]

Once i save.fig the plot, the legends gets squeezed into the plot and the name cut off (it is obviously too long, i know)

[image]

Can i somehow control the saved plot and how could i better place the legends without it hiding information of the plot?

Comment: `fig.savefig("name.pdf", bbox_inches="tight")` gives a similar figure than the one shown in the notebook.

Comment: Agree with @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, looks identical to me. ([Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHhKt.png)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As "ImportanceOfBeingErnest" pointed out in the comments, adding bbox_inches="tight" as parameter to the savefig function, solves the problem.